# Installing the workspace with Tomcat and samples

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ibm-sbt

I'm about to install the Social Business Toolkit, so i followed the instructions at the IBM SBD Wiki:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Social+Business+Toolkit+SDK+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Installing_the_workspace_with_Tomcat_and_samples_SDK1.0&content=pdcontent

Starting Tomcat i retrive some errors:

```
23.10.2013 12:11:38 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\WINNT\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32\Wbem;C:\WINNT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.ibm.sbt.dojo180' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:smartcloud.webapp' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.ibm.sbt.bootstrap211' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:acme.social.sample.webapp' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.ibm.sbt.web' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:acme.sample.webapp' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:acme.social.sample.dataapp' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:social.helloworld.webapp' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:helloworld.webapp' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.ibm.sbt.sample.web' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.ibm.sbt.jquery180' did not find a matching property.
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
23.10.2013 12:11:39 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
23.10.2013 12:11:40 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
23.10.2013 12:11:40 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2554 ms
23.10.2013 12:11:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
23.10.2013 12:11:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
23.10.2013 12:11:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\sbtk\workspaceWin\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\com.ibm.sbt.jquery180 does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
23.10.2013 12:11:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error in resourceStart()
23.10.2013 12:11:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error getConfigured
23.10.2013 12:11:49 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/sbt.jquery180] startup failed due to previous errors
23.10.2013 12:11:49 org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNUNG: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sbt.jquery180]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5495)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
23.10.2013 12:11:53 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
23.10.2013 12:11:53 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
23.10.2013 12:11:53 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
23.10.2013 12:11:53 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12306 ms
```

How can i get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery and dojo are thousands of files... 
these thousands of files are being copied from your working directory to your server (or more appropriately workspace's configuration folder for tomcat) 
when these files are copied it's within a time window, if that time window runs out, the system let's you move on, or gives a hint that all files are not published.

in this case, all files are not published, 
right click the server 
Click Publish or Refresh server

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still got the same problem after server / project clean and publish multiple times.